# Numpy indexing multidimensional arrays with array and slice

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

My doubt is about [this example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-index-arrays-with-slices) in the numpy docs.

`y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)`

This is the operation that I am trying to clarify:

`y[np.array([0,2,4]),1:3]`

According to the docs:
"In effect, the slice is converted to an index array np.array([[1,2]]) (shape (1,2)) that is broadcast with the index array to produce a resultant array of shape (3,2)."

This does not work, so I am assuming it is not equivalent

`y[np.array([0,2,4]), np.array([1,2])]`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-f4cd35e70141> in <module>()
----> 1 y[np.array([0,2,4]), np.array([1,2])]

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

How does this broadcasted array of shape (3,2) looks like?

Comment: Good catch. I've never used that particular usage pattern, but that result is certainly unexpected. Try using np.array([1,2])[:, None] as the second argument to make your "column indexing array" look like a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadcasting is more like:

```
In [280]: y[np.array([0,2,4])[...,None], np.array([1,2])]
Out[280]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [15, 16],
       [29, 30]])
```

I added a dimension to `[0,2,4]` making it 2d.  `broadcast_arrays` can be used to see what the broadcasted arrays look like:

```
In [281]: np.broadcast_arrays(np.array([0,2,4])[...,None], np.array([1,2]))
Out[281]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [2, 2],
        [4, 4]]), 
 array([[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]])]
```

`np.broadcast_arrays([[0],[2],[4]], [1,2])`  is the samething without the `array` wrappers.  `np.meshgrid([0,2,4], [1,2], indexing='ij')` is another way of producing these indexing arrays.

(the lists produced by `meshgrid` or `broadcast_arrays` could be used as the argument for `y[_]`.)

So it's right to say `[1,2]` is broadcast with the index array, but it omits the bit about adjusting dimensions.

A little earlier they have this example:

```
y[np.array([0,2,4])]
```

which is equivalent to `y[np.array([0,2,4]), :]`.  It picks 3 rows, and all items from them.  The `1:3` case can be thought of as an extension of this, picking 3 rows, and then 2 columns.

```
y[[0,2,4],:][:,1:3]
```

This might be a better way of thinking about the indexing if broadcasting is too confusing.

---

There's another docs page that might handle this better

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

In this docs, basic indexing involves slices and integers

```
y[:,1:3], y[1,:], y[1, 1:3]
```

Advanced indexing involves an array (or list)

```
y[[0,2,4],:]
```

This produces the same result as `y[::2,:]`, except the list case produces a copy, the slice (basic) a view.

`y[[0,2,4], [1,2,3]]` is a case of pure advance index array indexing, the result is 3 items, ones at `(0,1)`, `(2,2)`, and `(4,3)`.

`y[[0,2,4], 1:3]` is a case that this docs calls `Combining advanced and basic indexing`, 'advanced' from `[0,2,4]', basic from '1:3'.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

---

Looking at a more complex index array might add some insight.

```
In [222]: i=[[0,2],[1,4]]
```

Used with another list, it is 'pure' advanced, and the result is broadcasted:

```
In [224]: y[i, [1,2]]
Out[224]: 
array([[ 1, 16],
       [ 8, 30]])
```

The index arrays are:

```
In [234]: np.broadcast_arrays(i, [1,2])
Out[234]: 
[array([[0, 2],
        [1, 4]]), 
 array([[1, 2],
        [1, 2]])]
```

The `[1,2]` list is just expanded to a (2,2) array.

Using it with a slice is an example of this mixed advanced/basic, and the result is 3d `(2,2,2)`.

```
In [223]: y[i, 1:3]
Out[223]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [15, 16]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [29, 30]]])
```

The equivalent with broadcasting is

```
y[np.array(i)[...,None], [1,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

y[data,beginIndex:endIndex]

```
   import numpy as np
    y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
    print(y)
    [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
     [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
     [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
     [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
     [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]
    print(y[np.array([0,2,4]),1:3])
    [[ 1  2]
     [15 16]
     [29 30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the documentation may be incorrect here, or at least something is missing. I'd file [an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) for that, for clarification in the documentation.

In fact, [this part](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) of the documentation shows just this example, but then with the exception you get being raised:

```
>>> y[np.array([0,2,4]), np.array([0,1])]
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: shape mismatch: objects cannot be
broadcast to a single shape
```